# How to get ActiveForm creation time in GridView yii2?

Tags: yii2

I've created an `ActiveForm` and I want to add `created_at` attribute to the `GridView`. I added the column, but how to add the time, which would tell when the form was submitted? Here is my `GridView`:

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
        'attribute' => 'category_id',
        'value' => 'category.name',
        ],
        'title',
        'description:ntext',
        [
         'attribute' => 'created_at',
         'value' => '',
        ],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the format parameter and specify the format:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'created_at',
    'format'=>'dateTime',
],
```

You could also use 'time' instead of 'dateTime' if you only want the time.